# Express load Session from Mongo with session_id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, cordova, mongoose

Heylo,

I'm building a (semi) REST API with Nodejs/Express as back and Phonegap/Cordova as front.
For backend i'm using `express` with [`connect-mongo`](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo) and [`mongoose`](http://mongoosejs.com/) as following :

```
express.cookieParser(),
express.session({
    secret: nconf.get('session:salt'),
    store: new mongoStore({url: nconf.get('database').url})
}),
```

for session validation on node i've create the following function inside my `route.js` file

```
var authenticate = function (req, res, next) {

if (req.session.user)
    next();
else
    res.error('access is not authentication');
}
```

**Unfortunately PhoneGap and Cordova do not support cookies out of the box** so i use `localStorage`
to store session_id and wrap every server call to aggregate it to the url params.

Is there any elegant way to pre-load the session from mongoDB inside my `authenticate` function by the 'session_id' param without creating a `Schema` for the session collection and try querying it with mongoose?

Cheers,

-PK.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `store.get` method of your `mongoStore`. Try something like this:

```
var authenticate = function (req, res, next) {
  mongoStore.get(req.params.session_id, function (error, session) {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
      return;
    }
  }
  req.session = session;
  next();
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the serialized session is different from the session object being injected by `connect-mongo`, so if i use the above as a middleware which being called after 
`express.session({
        secret: nconf.get('session:salt'),
        cookie: {secure: false, maxAge: 300000},
        store: mStore
    })`

ill get an exception, if I reverse the middleware order so it will be deserialized before `connect-mongo` , then it will inject and override my loaded session object.

catch-22.

Comment: to be more precise here is the deserialization failure as a gist https://gist.github.com/kaminskypavel/e4f19bdb43899fa09389

Comment: Yeah you'll have to put a real session instance there in the way connect expects. I don't know those details off the top of my head though so I can't help with that aspect.